# how to associate/relate one impediment with multiple tasks in tfs

Tags: .net, tfs

currently, I am having multiple tasks which are stucked up due to impediment.

These are all different tasks with different parents. Do I need to create the impediments again and again in each task?

Or else, is there any mechanism through which we can associate/relate one impediment with multiple tasks?

### Edited:

Assuming that UserStory1 is having Task1,Task2,Task3. Now if Task1 is having sub Tasks i.e. Task4,Task5, Task6. And Task2 is having sub Tasks - Task7, Task8. Task3 is having - Task9 & Task10.

Here is the Hierarchy: -

```
UserStory1
  |  
  |__ Task1 
  |     |  
  |     |__ Task4 (having Impediment)
  |     |  
  |     |__ Task5
  |     |  
  |     |__ Task6 (having Impediment)
  |  
  |__ Task2 
  |     |  
  |     |__ Task7
  |     |  
  |     |__ Task8 (having Impediment)
  |  
  |__ Task3 
        |  
        |__ Task9 (having Impediment)
        |  
        |__ Task10
```

Now, if Task4,Task6,Task8,Task9 are stucked up because of having same impediment then how to create one impediment and associate it to above specified multiple tasks?

Comment: Do not know what you exactly mean with your question but going to try to answer it still. In one task you can add multiple links, so in the other way it should be possible also. We create 1 userstory and we have multiple tasks under it. This is though in TFS 2012 but I think it is also possible in TFS 2010.

Comment: @TimVK, please find the modification in the question

Comment: In TFS2012 there you can add a link to an existing `Related` work item. Here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff731580(v=vs.100).aspx] is some more information about it but just use `Link to ...` instead of `New linked work item...`

Comment: I think the question behind was, if Impediment requires a 1-to-1 relation or if a n-to-n is possible. As TimVK linked (the url is broken when I use his: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff731580.aspx) it is a n-to-n relation and you only need to have one Impediment for all tasks with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Predecessor` link in each `Task` and link to the `Impediment` in question.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293534.aspx